# Ask a question, answer with no solution and accept?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, self-answer

What should we do, if a user asks a question, answer with an unacceptable solution to his/her own question and accept?

[How to customized thick box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2107044/1427849)

Comment: Evaluate both the question and the answer as you normally would.

Comment: Downvote and move on.

Comment: Note that the question has now been deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You can a comment on his answer and request him to add the solution in the answer instead of just a comment. If the OP doesn't response you, you should downvote the answer and also flag the answer (because it looks like a comment.) And yes! if you have a solution then post it.

In the given example the OP has not visited the site for last 3 years so flagging is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

I would flag the reply with a *low quality* flag; it may also be considered a *not an answer*. After that, I'll leave a comment on the reply asking OP for a detailed explanation of what they "actually" did!

Comment: +1 but depends on how "low quality."  I generally don't think "wrong" answers meet this, as mods can't evaluate that.  I'd leave a blatant comment and dowvnote at least.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly why own accepted answers are not automatically shown on the top of the answer list.

Answer with a better answer, and have it upvoted enough so it's shown on the top of that list.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to choose in between these options

1. You can suggest user that it is not a really helpful answer in comments also explain why and what he can do for making it better
2. You can simply downvote the answer and add a comment to the answer explaining why
3. You can flag the answer as a low quality answer but better approach would be to flag the answer for moderator attention and add description in other why you want to flag the question.

Sometimes down vote will not be helpful simply down voting does not explain what was wrong